# Logistic Regression with independently weighted regularization terms

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification

For a standard logistic regression problem I'm interested in examining the impact of individual weighting of the parameters and in general the impact of regularization for completely separable data.

Does anyone know of a package in python which allows individual regularization weights for each parameter?

Thanks

(logistic regression, not SSE).

Comment: That is using linear regression.

Comment: If you read the `glmnet` documentation, you'll find that you can specify common GLMs very easily, including logistic regression.

Comment: I see, is there a python or matlab version? I don't use R.

Comment: Yes. This is the first result for a Google search of "glmnet python." https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet_python/ The bottom of the page also has a link to a Matlab version.